# Jquery.live() observing load new element in the DOM

Tags: jquery, load, live

Is it possible to observe the the "load"event when elements have been created in the DOM? More specific, I'm interested in observing if new select boxes have been added, and then sort the options in the selectbox.

I've tried stuff like:

```
$("select").live("load", mySortSelectFunction)
```

This apparently does not work. Maybe the "load" event doesn't fire on the select element?

If there is no "load" event, then how would it be possible to get a notification when a select box is ready in the DOM? I want to avoid firing some custom event from code everywhere the selectboxes are created. I want to just add one little eventlistener in a global script, and then all selectboxes are automatically sorted no matter when they are created.

Kind regards,

Christian Sonne Jensen

Comment: Work on your old open questions before you ask new ones.

Comment: Pls elaborate on this? Do I have some open questions related to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try [jquery liveQuery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) - it does exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such event or functionality that you can achieve. You can basically try to find all select elements on page load and then apply the sorting function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("select").each(function(){
    mySortSelectFunction(this);
  });

});
```

Comment: Yes, that is an option, but I'm maintaining a FAT javascript client with tons of ajax that hauls 100's of html snippets and place them into the DOM. What I really need is a generic listener that will observe when a snippet contains a selectbox. Otherwise I'll have to identify every place a selectbox is made and make some explicit call to notify the selectboxSorter.